# Changing table value based on another table in BIRT

Tags: java, mysql, birt

I have looked all over and can't seem to find anything on if this is possible, so I went here. Anyway, here's my problem.

I have a query that calculates the average survey score of particular groups per month, outputs something like:

```
GRP1    71.2
GRP2    77.2
GRP3    81.6
```

Now I have another table with criteria for getting a point value based on these, something like:

```
min_value    max_value     point
   95           100         80
   85            94         60
   75            84         40
   65            74         20
```

Basically means 95-100 should get a score of 80, etc. This is dynamic (user in my application can change these values or add/remove rows) so I thought of writing a script on a label for the first table, looking up the second table, comparing it to the min and max values. However I've looked around and I didn't see anything on how to do this. I thought of somehow converting the data set into a list of objects that can be looped through so I can compare the value with each row, but I don't know how to do this.

EDIT: I've discovered a way but it involves me joining the second table to the first, then setting the visibility property so that the rows where the score is not between the min and max values are not shown. However I have doubts about the efficiency of this so I want to know if there's a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to display data from the second table, right? The table just defines value boundaries. If so, you can preload data form the second table in a javascript object, by adding an invisible table to your report that is bound to the second database table. That table item must be placed before the report item displaying data from the first table.

You will have to program a bit in Javascript:

- create 2 datasets: one for each db table
- add a table that is bound to the second dataset
- make this table invisible: Property Editor -> Visibility tab. The table is there just to make the second data set loading data from the database
- create beforeOpen() event handle for the second dataset
- define a new global variable in the beforeOpen() script: gValueMapping = []; This variable will keep a two-dimension array: [size of the second table][2]
- create onFetch() event handler for the second dataset
- add current row values to the global variable gValueMapping: gValueMapping.push([row["min_value"], row["point"]]). If you sort the second dataset by min_value, you don't need to know the max_value.
- now create a new databinding for the table bound to the first table
- program the binding as follows: iterate over the gValueMapping in the reversed order until your current value is less than the value in the gValueMapping[i][0], then return gValueMapping[i][1]. It contains the corresponding "point" value.

Answer (score 0):

In the "Edit Data Set" make a "computed column"

Here is an exmaple of JavaScript I use for a simular issue, but I am converting a number to a word string.

```
if (row["Change Assessment"]==1){
"Very High"
}else if (row["Change Assessment"]==2){
"High"
}else if (row["Change Assessment"]==3){
"Low"
}else if (row["Change Assessment"]==4){
"Very Low"
}else {
"Undefined"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient and easy way would be to do this in a stored procedure of your database: we store the aggregated survey by month in a temporary table, and then we join it to the min-max table.

For a solution in BIRT only, we could create a joined dataset:

- Add a fictive column, with values always set to "1" (or whatever constant value you like...) to each of your 2 existing datasets.
- Create a new "joined dataset" between these 2 datasets, and use our fictive column to link them so that we get a "cartesian product"
- In "Filters" tab of the joined dataset, add a new filter to select rows with a score of survey between min-max
- That's it!